# Is it obvious that $P(X_1 < X_3 | X_1 < X_2) = \int_0^R f_{X_1}(x_1 | X_1 < X_2)P(x_1 < X_3) dx_1 dx_2dx_3$ without Bayes rule?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are IID and bounded by $[0, R]$.

Why is it *obvious* that

$$
P(X_1 < X_3 | X_1 < X_2) = \int_0^R f_{X_1}(x_1 | X_1 < X_2)P(x_1 < X_3) dx_1 
$$
?

I think I could get to this formula by using Bayes rule, but in my notes, it seems this result was readily known, and it's not clear to me how that is.

Is it some variant of the law of total probability applied to a conditional probability?

Comment: I think there should not be a $dx_2 \ dx_3$ on the right-hand side

Comment: @angryavian Fixed (Still have the same question, however)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it some variant of the law of total probability applied to a conditional probability?

Yes.  <s>It also relies on the fact that the variables are independent so the events $X_1<X_3$ and $X_1<X_2$ are conditionally independent for a given value of $X_1$ .</s>
$$\require{cancel}\color{red}{\xcancel{\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1=x, X_1<X_2) &=\mathsf P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1=x)\\[1ex] &=\mathsf P(x<X_3)\end{align}}}$$

<s>Then</s> $$\color{red}{\xcancel{\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1<X_2)&=\int_0^R f_{X_1}(x)\,\mathsf P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1=x, X_1<X_2)\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_0^R f_{X_1}(x)\,\mathsf P(x<X_3)\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_0^R \tfrac 1R\cdot\tfrac{R-x}{R}\,\mathrm d x&&\text{If uniformly distributed}\\&=\tfrac 12\end{align}}}$$

---

Hold on, something seems wrong here. When given that $X_1$ is small, the conditional probability that $X_3$ exceeds it should be greater that the unconditional probability.

Ah, indeed.  In fact the events $X_1<X_2$ and $X_1<X_3$ are *not* conditionally independent when given $X_1$. Rather the events $x<X_2$ and $x<X_3$ are conditionally independent when given $X_1=x$ (since the random variables are mutually independent).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1<X_2)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X_1< X_2\cap X_1<X_3)}{\mathsf P(X_1<X_2)}\\&=2 \mathsf P(X_1<X_2\cap X_1<X_3)\\&=2\int_0^R f_{X_1}(x)\,\mathsf P(x < X_2\cap x< X_3\mid X_1=x)\,\mathrm d x\\&=2\int_0^R f_{X_1}(x)\,\mathsf P(x < X_2)\mathsf P(x< X_3)\,\mathrm d x\\&=2\int_0^R R^{-3}(R-x)^2\,\mathrm d x &&\text{If uniformly distributed}\\&=\tfrac 23\end{align}$$

So you should have been given: $$\mathsf P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1<X_2)=\dfrac{\int_0^R f_{\small X_1}(x)\,\mathsf P(x<X_2)\,\mathsf P(x<X_3)\,\mathrm d x}{\int_0^R f_{\small X_1}(x)\,\mathsf P(x<X_2)\,\mathrm d x}$$

Comment: Doesn't it also rely on the relationship between joint and conditional probability? The way I see it is $P(X_1 < X_3 | X_1 < X_2) = \int_0^R f_{X_1}(x_1, X_1 < X_3 | X_1 < X2) dx_1$. And then you have to apply the relationship between joint and conditional probability to get to the RHS?

Comment: Actually, I think the subscript not the pdf isn't really correct. That's really a joint pdf-pmf since $x_1$ is continuous and $X_1 < X_3$ is discrete

Comment: Rather, $X_1<X_2$ and $X_1<X_3$ are *events* and mixing that into a pdf is an awkward notation, so we go straight to the conditional expression. $$\def\P{\mathsf P}\begin{align} \mathsf P(A\mid B)&=\int_0^R f_{X_1}(x)\,\P(A\mid X_1=x, B)\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]\P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1<X_2)&=\int_0^R f_{X_1}(x)\,\P(X_1<X_3\mid X_1=x, X_1<X_2)\,\mathrm d x\\&= \int_0^R f_{X_1}(x)\,\P(x<X_3)\,\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

Comment: @roulette01 Hold on, something seems wrong here. ...  Yeah, the *events* $X_1<X_2$ and $X_1<X_3$ are *not* in fact conditionally independent of the value of $X_1$.  Rather, it is the events $x<X_2$, and $x<X_3$ that are so.

Comment: Wait, you assumed $X_1, X_2, X_3 \sim U(0, R)$? That seems to be because of $(R-x)^2$, but then you have $f_{X_1}(x) = \frac{1}{R^3}$?

Comment: Ah, no I have $f_{X_1}(x)=R^{-1}$ , $\mathsf P(x<X_2)= R^{-1}(R-x)$, and $\mathsf P(x<X_3)= R^{-1}(R-x)$.  But, yeah, that is for Uniform IID distributions on that bound, where I see now that you have only stated *identical and independently* distributed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123611/discussion-between-graham-kemp-and-roulette01).

Answer (score 0):

Let events be defined bt $A=(X_1\le X_3)$, $B=X_1\le X_2)$, and $C=(X_2\le X_3)$  So $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

The numerator $P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C')=P(X_1\le X_2\le X_3)+P(X_1\le X_3\lt X_2)$$=\int\limits_0^R\int\limits_0^{x_3}\int\limits_0^{x_2}f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)f_3(x_3)dx_1dx_2dx_3$$+\int\limits_0^R\int\limits_0^{x_2}\int\limits_0^{x_3}f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)f_3(x_3)dx_1dx_3dx_2$

The denominator  $P(B)=P(X1\le X_2)=\int\limits_0^R\int\limits_0^{x_2}f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)dx_1dx_2$

Comment: I'm confused what this answer means. What do $I,J$ represent here?

Comment: $I=P(X_1\le X_3|(X_1\le X_2)\cap (X_2\le X_3))$ and $J=P(X_1\le X_3|(X_1\le X_2)\cap (X_2\gt X_3))$.   Therefore $I+J=P(X_1\le X_3|X_1\le X_2)$

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: No.  $\mathsf P(X_1\leqslant X_3\mid X_1\leqslant X_2) = I\,\mathsf P(X_2\leqslant X_3\mid X_1\leqslant X_2)+J\,\mathsf P(X_2 > X_3\mid X_1\leqslant X_2)$, by the Law of Total Probability.  Which will not help make thing easier.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't understand the connection between your comment and my result. $X_2\le X_3$ and $X_2\gt X_3$ are complementary events so adding two probabilities of the event $(X_1\le X_3|X_1\le X_2)$ where these are the conditions removes the conditions.

Comment: You join them to the event, not to the condition. The Law of Total Probability says: $$P(A\mid C)~{=P(A\cap B\mid C)+P(A\cap B^\complement\mid C)\\=\underbrace{P(A\mid B\cap C)}_{\text{your }I}P(B\mid C)+\underbrace{P(A\mid B^\complement\cap C)}_{\text{your }J}P(B^\complement\mid C)}$$

Comment: @Graham Kemp You are correct.  (I always had a problem with conditional probability)  I have rewritten my answer accordingly.